# Open two records in the same kanban view - Odoo14

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I have a question regarding the way Odoo works, is it possible to open two records in the same screen when you select them?

The result that i am looking for is to "compare the two records in the same screen"

[image: attaching image for reference.]

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know it can't. What comes to mind is that when more than one record is selected it allows you to open a wizard showing you the differences.